# Axiom X - All consistent large cardinals exist?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I want to know if there are any papers or research along the following lines. From a philosophical point of view there is no reason to think size has a limit, if we can describe it it exists, provided it does not contradict the axioms of our favourite set theory.

I think this can be expressed as a meta-axiom schema as follows. Let $AX$ be the set of axioms you like in the language $<\in >$ of set theory.

Axiom X - Let $\varphi $ be a statement with one free variable $\kappa$. If $AX\cup \{Cardinal[\kappa ], \varphi\}$ is consistent then $\exists\kappa\varphi$ is an axiom.$\square$

I would like to know if this could be converted to an internal axiom, or axiom schema, of set theory using extenders or such like. This would result in a non-conservative but consistent set theory in which all large cardinals exist.

Comment: The problem is how do you know that they are consistent ? You cant even prove that an inaccessible cardinal is consistent. So the axiom may have no provable consequences.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus you can't prove consistency within, but I think you can prove consistency outside?

Comment: @KennyLau Outside set theory ? Assuming what ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I mean, in the meta-theory. OP did say that the schema is meta.

Comment: @KennyLau What meta theory ? Set theory may be meta to other theories but nothing is meta to set theory.

Comment: You need some sort of restriction on what $\varphi$ can be (and that seems very difficult to formalize).  Otherwise this theory is obviously inconsistent (take $\varphi$ to be any statement independent of $AX$ and its negation).

Comment: As @Rene said, assumptions of consistency come at the cost of involving the meta-theory quite heavily. It is perfectly reasonable that ZFC with an inaccessible cardinal is inconsistent, and surely this is the case if your meta-theory is ZFC+$\lnot$Con(ZFC). Similarly, one can argue that something like "a proper class of I0 cardinals and a proper class of extendible cardinals" would provide you with enough consistency to most large cardinal axioms to hold.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah but its kind of weird to assume large cardinals to then prove consistency of large cardinals. Not that we have much of a choice.

Comment: @Rene: Yes, very much so. But we don't have any other way to escape the trap set by Gödel...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Trap. You make him out like a bad guy.

Comment: Besides the obvious flaw in your question that Eric pointed out, see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1843972/21820) and Noah's answer that gives an axiom with large cardinal strength that contradicts existence of an inaccessible cardinal!

Comment: Thanks, I know its very tricky. How about this then as a candidate for axiom X. For all cardinals $\kappa$ and $\lambda$  with $\kappa <\lambda$ there is a $(\kappa,\lambda)$ extender $E$. From $E$ I believe we can construct an inner model $M$ and an elementary embedding $j$ that validates a large cardinal axiom. Different $\kappa,\lambda$ give different extenders that validate different large cardinals. In this way a large number of large cardinals get brought into existence by an internal axiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very clearly inconsistent, e.g. "There exists an inaccessible cardinal greater than all other inaccessible cardinals that is less than the least 1-inaccessible cardinal," "There exists a Σ<sub>2</sub>-reflecting cardinal."